# Constante en js igual a unas coordenadas

Tags: javascript

estoy tratando de hacer que un script en javascript compruebe si una contraseña es igual a la que debe ser, pero soy incapaz de hacerlo, porque tengo problemas con las comillas. El siguiente código seria el intento de declaración. Se que debería ponerlo entere comillas como "" o '', pero son usadas en las coordenadas, como se haría entonces, si es posible.

```
const passwordcorrecta = 32°32′46″ N, 16°31′31″ W;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar [plantillas de texto](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) encerrando la cadena entre acentos graves:

```
const passwordcorrecta = `32°32′46″ N, 16°31′31″ W`;
```

Answer (score 1):

@Parritoso si tienes una comilla en un string solamente tienes que ponerle una barra:

```
const passwordcorrecta = '32°32\'46″ N, 16°31\'31″ W';
```

De esta manera te coge la comilla como texto en vez de romperte la cadena.